# static initialization of members of class of the same class in c++

Tags: c++, static

I dont know exactly how to call it in c++ but what i trying to do is to create 
General class that represent Color , with several  members of that class are same type of the class something like this : ( not working )

```
class Color
{
public:
    Color();
    Color(const Color& color);
    Color(float r, float g, float b, float a);
    ~Color();
   static const Color CLEAR;
   static const Color WHITE;
   static const Color BLACK;
   static const Color RED;

private:
    void set(Color color);
    / 
    float r, g, b, a;
};
```

///The c++ file :
    #include "Color.h"

```
 Color CLEAR(0, 0, 0, 0);
 Color WHITE(1, 1, 1, 1);
 Color BLACK(0, 0, 0, 1);
 Color RED(1, 0, 0, 1);

Color::Color()
{
}
Color::Color(float r, float g, float b, float a) 
{
    r = r;
    g = g;
    b = b;
    a = a;

}
Color::Color(Color& color)
{
    set(color);
}
void Color::set(Color color)
{
    r = color.r;
    g = color.g;
    b = color.b;
    a = color.a;

}
Color::~Color()
{
}
```

so from code i could call :

```
Color c = Color::WHITE; // or Color.WHITE
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your constants reside inside `Color`, you have to define them like this:

```
const Color Color::CLEAR(0, 0, 0, 0);
//          ^^^^^^^
//          Qualification of static class member.
//
// Instead of:
Color CLEAR(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify your `static` members in their definitions:

```
Color Color::WHITE(1,1,1,1);
// ...
```

Otherwise, you're declaring unrelated variables.